# PHP sending text to a <input type="text">

Tags: php, xhtml

How would I send information from a form to a block of PHP code and then back to a text area? I can not find this answer.

Comment: Your question is very very basic. My suggestion would be to follow this tutorial : http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/diving-into-php/ It'll be really helpful

Comment: @JohnP  I know but what I am trying to do is display my result in a text box but all the basic tutorials I had read or went with really did not displayed that they just say echo "something to document";

Answer (score 5):

To print out the text you entered in the textfield on the next request would look like this assuming you render the same page (i.e. myform.php):

```php
<?php
  $fieldValue = htmlentities($_POST['myfield']);
?>

<form action="myform.php" method="post">
  <label for="myfield">Your textfield:</label>
  <input type="text" name="myfield" id="myfield" value="<?php echo $fieldValue; ?>" />
</form>
```

Comment: Don't forget to escape $textfieldvalue with htmlspecialchars

Comment: So I would not put name I would part Id instead?

Comment: @Emil Vikström: Yes, good to point that out but I think it is out of scope for the given question.

Comment: @daddycardona: Using the name-attribute für form elements is always good because it is not guaranteed that the id is respected by the browser. Using the id-attribute helps to add labels to your form and reference form elements.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic example.

Assuming you have a PHP file named index.php

```
<?php 
  $val = 'Nothing in POST';
  if (!empty($_POST)) { //$_POST is where stuff posted from the FORM is saved
    $val = isset($_POST['text']) ? $_POST['text'] : '';//you're looking for the data with key text which is the name of your textarea element
    $val = 'Got something from POST : ' . $val;
  }
?>


<form action='index.php' method='post'>
  <textarea name='text'><?php echo $val ?></textarea>
</form>
```

Have a look at this tutorial for the basics : http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/diving-into-php/

Comment: that is what I am talking about, I want to take like two values add them together and the have my result be posted in the text area.

Comment: is that you these tutorials are pretty bad ass so far thanks for your site.

Answer (score 0):

use ajax!(and use jquery for that ajax!)

suppose you have this html :

```
<input type="text" id="input">
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
```

than the script should be:

```
$('#input').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.wich != 13)//not enter
        return;
    $.get(your_php_file.php,{param1:val1,param2:val2},function(result){
        $('#result').val(result);
    });
});
```

when you hit enter on the input field,the ajax function is being called that requests the file `your_php_file.php?param1=val1&param2=val2`. With the php's result, the callback function is being called which updates your textarea